# How can I find what pages contains links to the page I am editing?

Tags: hyperlink, pages, move

There is one specific page I am editing or I am about to delete and I want to know what pages are referring to this one (so as e. g. not to have links leading nowhere).

I can find that there are "x" pages containing a hyperlink to this page (by lets say trying to rename the page) but I cannot found out those pages.

How can I find them?

Comment: have you referenced the link to the page(that you want to delete) in the 'content' of your SharePoint pages and that is what your are looking to find out ?